# Stream dynamic image from Spring MVC endpoint without holding it in memory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-s3, inputstream

I have a `@Controller` that returns an image to the front end, but currently it holds the whole thing in memory as a byte array before returning a `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` object.

I would like to change this so that it just streams the image out without having to hold all the requested images in memory first.

These are not static images on the file system but rather images stored in Amazon S3, we are looking into utilizing CloudFront in the future, but for now we have to act as a middle man to retrieve the files.

I found an example that I coded below however again the image is read and held as a byte array in memory as the `write` function needs a byte array.

Is there any way to do this without using a lot of memory?

This is going to be used in a system where the client will open a page filled with images, each having multiple levels of resolution, the client is requesting the images very rapidly so the backend has to provide the images without using all of the memory resources.

Client:

```
<img src="{root}/image/123/low/3" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Backend what I have now:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{id}/{quality}/{pageNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public void retrieveImage(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String quality, @PathVariable Integer pageNumber,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
byte[] imageBytes = getImageFromS3(id, quality, pageNumber);
return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(imageBytes, createCachingStrategy(), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Something I found online:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{id}/{quality}/{pageNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public void retrieveImage(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String quality, @PathVariable Integer pageNumber,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

    //Open connection
    S3Object s3Object = imageService.getS3Object(quality, pageNumber, id)
    S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectIS = s3Object.getObjectContent();

    response.getOutputStream().write(IOUtils.toByteArray(s3ObjectIS));

    //Then close connection to amazon......
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353095/streaming-dynamic-files-from-spring-mvc?rq=1 may provide some insight through the implementations of AbstractPdfView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on one thing. You should never completely load a file to memory. Files have sizes which may exceed the total RAM capacity (5 Gb, 10 Gb) thus it is not a reliable way to handle files. Using `IOUtils.toByteArray()` reads an InputStream and loads it to a single byte array which is not a good thing.

What you should do is read chunk by chunk and write whenever you finish reading a chunk. More like streaming. See code change below. Here for any given time for a image there will be only 8 * 2048 bytes or 2 Kb of RAM will be used. You can increase it if you want stream faster.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{id}/{quality}/{pageNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public void retrieveImage(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String quality, @PathVariable Integer pageNumber,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

    //Open connection
    S3Object s3Object = imageService.getS3Object(quality, pageNumber, id)
    S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectIS = s3Object.getObjectContent();

    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    int read = 0;
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    while((read = s3ObjectIS.read(data)) > 0) {
        out.write(data, 0, read);
        out.flush();
    }
    out.close();

    //Then close connection to amazon......
}
```